# RemoveFromSuperview specific views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I add some UIViews to my view using following method:

```
[self.view addSubview:myStickerView]; // this line is called every time when I select a button from ScrollView.
```

So, I can have a lot of `myStickerView` on my `self.view`.

Now, when I call this line: `[myStickerView removeFromSuperview];` it will remove only my last `myStickerView`.

How can I remove all UIViews (`myStickerView`)?

Comment: why don't you check if self.view.subviews already contains myStickerView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be something like this:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MYStickerView class]) {
        [view removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Or you can store references for all inserted sticker views not to go through every subview

Comment: This is not a good solution. You would have to do a recursive search if you had sticker views in subviews of the main view.

Comment: I agree, I think I mentioned what you mean right after the code sample. If it was me I would have an "insertedStickerView" array that references all the stickers. I assumed that all the stickers had the common superview from this line [self.view addSubview:myStickerView], so for such case looping through all the subviews is also an option.

Comment: Hey, that sounds like my answer ;)

Comment: I started typing mine before I saw yours, anyways, you are right, and I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: Now, If in myStickerView have some methods, how can I access them using loop? I have a method what hides editing tools from myStickerView, and I call it like: [myStickerView hideTools]; tell me please, how to access this method for all stickers from NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to have an NSMutableArray property that kept track of your sticker views. When you add a sticker view to your view, add it to the array as well, that way you could do something like this when you wanted to remove all the sticker views

```
-(void)removeStickerViews
{
    for(StickerView *stickerView in self.myStickerViewArray)
    {
        [stickerView doSomething];
        [stickerView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.myStickerViewArray removeAllObjects];
}

-(void)addStickerView:(StickerView *)inStickerView
{
    [self.myStickerViewArray addObject:inStickerView];
    [self.view addSubview:inStickerView];
}
```

Comment: Now, If in myStickerView have some methods, how can I access them using loop?

I have a method what hides editing tools from myStickerView, and I call it like: [myStickerView hideTools]; tell me please, how to access this method for all stickers from NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of keeping track in an array is fine, but I suggest using the more elegant [myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)] to achieve the result.