# Access methods from UIView class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have .m and .h files which helps me to control an UIView (resize, move, and more).

I posted here: [RemoveFromSuperview specific views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19326954/2805816) to ask how to remove all subviews from my superview.

I got the idea with loop, and works great.

Now I would like to access a method from my UIView.

```
[myStickerView hideTools];
```

The method hides some buttons from myStickerView.

I used this code, to call `hideTools` method, but doesn't work.

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[myStickerView class]) {
        [myStickerView hideTools];
    }
}
```

What's the problem? Help me please. I want to call `hideTools` for all `myStickerView`s from `self.view.subviews`.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to improve my answer. What is the name of your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your `hideTools` method is only available from your `myStickerView` class.

In that case you'd want to call hideTools from that class:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[myStickerView class]) {
        [(myStickerView *)view hideTools];
    }
}
```

Edit: I answered at the same time with others :( but if you don't cast view to `myStickerView`, you'd get a warning.

Comment: I dont think that's the proper cast... myStickerView is an instance

Comment: @LuisCien That is true, but we don't know the name of that class yet. I will update the answer if we learned the name of the class.

Comment: [myStickerView class] indicates the name of the class, not instance, is myStickerView (since `class` is a class method not an instance method). However, that may just be a mistake by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
if ([view isKindOfClass:[myStickerView class]) {
    [view hideTools];
}
```

Comment: you need to cast view to myStickerView in order to call hideTools

Answer (score 0):

First, there are not such object call `myStickerView` in your for-loop.

And the `view` in subviews is declared to `UIView` class.

Here is my suggestion

```
for (myStickerView *stickerView in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([stickerView isKindOfClass:[myStickerView class]) {
      [stickerView hideTools];
    }
```

or force target subviews to declare to your class

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[myStickerView class]) {
          [(myStickerView *)view hideTools];
        }
```